# Type within namespace in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces

Suppose I defined `A::B::int`, how can I refer to the standard C++ `int` inside `A::B`?

Comment: A better question is: How did you get away with declaring something with the identifier `int` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a typedef named `int`, even if it is in a namespace.  `int` is a keyword.

Keywords are reserved for their specific uses and you cannot use them for any other purpose in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

$3.4.2/2-

`'If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.`

This means that fundamental types do not have any namespace associated with them.

So you can't even say ::int for this reason.

Comment: Except you can:  since you cannot have a typedef named `int`, `int` will always be the fundamental integral type `int`.  :-)

Comment: What that means is that passing an `int` argument will never pee on your namespace and summon a foreign function from a namespace in a distant land.

Comment: BTW, you can't say `::int` because such a string can't be formed by the grammar production rules of the standard.

Comment: Actually, the grammar rules allow it. The grammar production rules for an identifier don't distinguish between `int` and `inT`. The rejection happens (logically) at a different level: after the grammar produces an identifier with a spelling that matches a keyword.